# How to configure webpack to use ng2-translate in Angular2

Tags: json, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I was following Ocombe's ng2-translate example [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/btpW3l0jr5beJVjohy1Q?p=preview). I see that it is example of System.js

```
System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {
    'app': "./src",
    'ng2-translate': 'npm:ng2-translate',
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
     ..........
     ..........

  }
```

How do I configure ng2-translate with webpack? Where I have to mention the en.json and fr.json files path (path-src/main/app/assets/i18n/.json) in webpack configuration files?

Comment: https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate#configuration

Comment: @ranakrunal9 I followed that example but I'm getting Json file not found 404 error. I'm not understanding where do I need to mention those files in webpack

Comment: check the URL path like `http://localhost:3000/#/assets/i18n/en.json` in console where `ng2-translate` service is checking file and make sure that file exists at that place. As you are using `webpack` may be you forgot to copy that files in you build folder.

Comment: Check this [example](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/tree/master/examples/webpack)..

Comment: @ranakrunal9 I see that its failing to load the JSON files. The example I'm following, no where I see those Json files mentioned or the path. Not understanding how those Json files are referenced. [link]https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/tree/master/examples/webpack

Answer (score 0):

Hey I guess you need to add this function to your app.module:

```
    export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
            return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "assets/i18n/", ".json");
    }
```